# iOS: How do recognize MICR using Tesseract

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, tesseract, micr

My requirement is to recognize MICR code from a cheque. I already referred LEADTOOL for MICR recognizer and it's need paid code for MICR recognizer.

What is the easiest way to recognize MICR code using Tesseract in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Copy `mcr.traineddata` (attached to one of the [Tesseract-OCR Groups posts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/tesseract-ocr/micr/tesseract-ocr/obWI4cz8rXg/_Yl8RuCeJAkJ)) to `tessdata` folder, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have attached MICR trained data with this post.Please download it and use in your code.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/anh3ooifn2c7xin/mcr.traineddata.zip?dl=0

And also you can generate customize trained data using tesseract. Please refer below link.

https://blog.cedric.ws/how-to-train-tesseract-301

Thanks.

Comment: Hello my friend, I'm also facing the same issue. Did you solve it? Do you have any example project? Thank you.